# Problemas com Chosen-select

Tags: jquery

Olá.

Eu havia criado um select que fazia a busca dos cadastro e ao digitar ele selecionava de acordo com o que eu buscava.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, de uma hora para outra ele começou a dar bugs. Parece que tem um input dentro do outro (digite o nome da igreja). Quando clico nesse input, ele apresenta várias coisas, como letras que nada tem haver com o conteúdo do banco de dados. O que pode estar acontecendo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**PHP e HTML**

```
<label for="id_empresa">* Digite o nome da Igreja:</label>
            <select name="id_empresa" data-placeholder="Escolha uma Igreja" class="chosen-select">
              <option value=""></option>

<?php 
                        #seleciona os dados da tabela cargos_diretoria
                        $query_igreja = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT id_empresa, nome_empresa FROM empresa");

                        while($igreja = mysqli_fetch_array($query_igreja)) { ?>
                     <option value="<?php echo $igreja['id_empresa'] ?>"><?php echo $igreja['nome_empresa'] ?></option>
                     <?php } ?>
        </select>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chosen-select {
  width: 100%; }

.chosen-select-deselect {
  width: 100%; }

.chosen-container {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle; }
  .chosen-container .chosen-drop {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    margin-top: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: -9000px;
    z-index: 1060; }
  .chosen-container.chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop {
    left: 0;
    right: 0; }
  .chosen-container .chosen-results {
    color: #555555;
    margin: 0 4px 4px 0;
    max-height: 240px;
    padding: 0 0 0 4px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; }
    .chosen-container .chosen-results li {
      display: none;
      line-height: 1.42857;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 5px 6px; }
      .chosen-container .chosen-results li em {
        background: #feffde;
        font-style: normal; }
      .chosen-container .chosen-results li.group-result {
        display: list-item;
        cursor: default;
        color: #999;
        font-weight: bold; }
      .chosen-container .chosen-results li.group-option {
        padding-left: 15px; }
      .chosen-container .chosen-results li.active-result {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: list-item; }
      .chosen-container .chosen-results li.highlighted {
        background-color: #337ab7;
        background-image: none;
        color: white; }
        .chosen-container .chosen-results li.highlighted em {
          background: transparent; }
      .chosen-container .chosen-results li.disabled-result {
        display: list-item;
        color: #777777; }
    .chosen-container .chosen-results .no-results {
      background: #eeeeee;
      display: list-item; }
  .chosen-container .chosen-results-scroll {
    background: white;
    margin: 0 4px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 321px;
    z-index: 1; }
    .chosen-container .chosen-results-scroll span {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 1.42857;
      text-indent: -5000px;
      width: 9px; }
  .chosen-container .chosen-results-scroll-down {
    bottom: 0; }
    .chosen-container .chosen-results-scroll-down span {
      background: url("chosen-sprite.png") no-repeat -4px -3px; }
  .chosen-container .chosen-results-scroll-up span {
    background: url("chosen-sprite.png") no-repeat -22px -3px; }

.chosen-container-single .chosen-single {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  color: #555555;
  display: block;
  height: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 34px;
  padding: 0 0 0 8px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap; }
  .chosen-container-single .chosen-single span {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 26px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap; }
  .chosen-container-single .chosen-single abbr {
    background: url("chosen-sprite.png") right top no-repeat;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 26px;
    top: 12px;
    width: 12px; }
    .chosen-container-single .chosen-single abbr:hover {
      background-position: right -11px; }
  .chosen-container-single .chosen-single.chosen-disabled .chosen-single abbr:hover {
    background-position: right 2px; }
  .chosen-container-single .chosen-single div {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 18px; }
    .chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b {
      background: url("chosen-sprite.png") no-repeat 0 7px;
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%; }
.chosen-container-single .chosen-default {
  color: #777777; }
.chosen-container-single .chosen-search {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 4px;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 1000; }
  .chosen-container-single .chosen-search input[type="text"] {
    background: url("chosen-sprite.png") no-repeat 100% -20px, #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    margin: 1px 0;
    padding: 4px 20px 4px 4px;
    width: 100%; }
.chosen-container-single .chosen-drop {
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box; }

.chosen-container-single-nosearch .chosen-search input[type="text"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9000px; }

.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  cursor: text;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 1%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative; }
  .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none; }
  .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices .search-field {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap; }
    .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices .search-field input[type="text"] {
      background: transparent !important;
      border: 0 !important;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
      color: #555555;
      height: 32px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 4px;
      outline: 0; }
    .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices .search-field .default {
      color: #999; }
  .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices .search-choice {
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #eeeeee 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #eeeeee 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, #eeeeee 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFEEEEEE', GradientType=0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    color: #333333;
    cursor: default;
    line-height: 13px;
    margin: 6px 0 3px 5px;
    padding: 3px 20px 3px 5px;
    position: relative; }
    .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices .search-choice .search-choice-close {
      background: url("chosen-sprite.png") right top no-repeat;
      display: block;
      font-size: 1px;
      height: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 4px;
      top: 5px;
      width: 12px;
      cursor: pointer; }
      .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices .search-choice .search-choice-close:hover {
        background-position: right -11px; }
  .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices .search-choice-focus {
    background: #d4d4d4; }
    .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices .search-choice-focus .search-choice-close {
      background-position: right -11px; }
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-results {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0; }
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-drop .result-selected {
  display: none; }

.chosen-container-active .chosen-single {
  border: 1px solid #66afe9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px #66afe9;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px #66afe9;
  -webkit-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s; }
.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #66afe9;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px #66afe9;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px #66afe9;
  -webkit-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s; }
  .chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div {
    background: transparent;
    border-left: none; }
    .chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div b {
      background-position: -18px 7px; }
.chosen-container-active .chosen-choices {
  border: 1px solid #66afe9;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px #66afe9;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px #66afe9;
  -webkit-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s; }
  .chosen-container-active .chosen-choices .search-field input[type="text"] {
    color: #111 !important; }
.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-choices {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0; }

.chosen-disabled {
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.5 !important; }
  .chosen-disabled .chosen-single {
    cursor: default; }
  .chosen-disabled .chosen-choices .search-choice .search-choice-close {
    cursor: default; }

.chosen-rtl {
  text-align: right; }
  .chosen-rtl .chosen-single {
    padding: 0 8px 0 0;
    overflow: visible; }
    .chosen-rtl .chosen-single span {
      margin-left: 26px;
      margin-right: 0;
      direction: rtl; }
    .chosen-rtl .chosen-single div {
      left: 7px;
      right: auto; }
    .chosen-rtl .chosen-single abbr {
      left: 26px;
      right: auto; }
  .chosen-rtl .chosen-choices .search-field input[type="text"] {
    direction: rtl; }
  .chosen-rtl .chosen-choices li {
    float: right; }
  .chosen-rtl .chosen-choices .search-choice {
    margin: 6px 5px 3px 0;
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 19px; }
    .chosen-rtl .chosen-choices .search-choice .search-choice-close {
      background-position: right top;
      left: 4px;
      right: auto; }
  .chosen-rtl.chosen-container-single .chosen-results {
    margin: 0 0 4px 4px;
    padding: 0 4px 0 0; }
  .chosen-rtl .chosen-results .group-option {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 15px; }
  .chosen-rtl.chosen-container-active.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div {
    border-right: none; }
  .chosen-rtl .chosen-search input[type="text"] {
    background: url("chosen-sprite.png") no-repeat -28px -20px, #fff;
    direction: rtl;
    padding: 4px 5px 4px 20px; }

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) {
  .chosen-rtl .chosen-search input[type="text"],
  .chosen-container-single .chosen-single abbr,
  .chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b,
  .chosen-container-single .chosen-search input[type="text"],
  .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices .search-choice .search-choice-close,
  .chosen-container .chosen-results-scroll-down span,
  .chosen-container .chosen-results-scroll-up span {
    background-image: url("chosen-sprite@2x.png") !important;
    background-size: 52px 37px !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important; } }

/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap-chosen.css.map */
```

Comment: Marcelo coloque os seus códigos na pergunta. Principalmente o PHP e o HTML, mas de preferencia coloca o CSS para podermos simular o erro de alguma forma.

Comment: Já atualizei.. Mas o css é muito grande